# Timeout function after 10 seconds Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timeout

I want to display a "Network Error" message if after 10 seconds of trying to connect, a login does not succeed.

How can I stop my login function after 10 seconds and show this error message?

I'm using AlamoFire.

I don't have the full implementation, but this is the skeleton of what I want my function to behave like:

```
func loginFunc() {

    /*Start 10 second timer, if in 10 seconds 
     loginFunc() is still running, break and show NetworkError*/


    <authentication code here>
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code that you wish to timeout.

Comment: Updated with function skeleton.

Comment: Update your question with your actual working code that you need to update with a timeout.

Comment: I don't have the full working code yet. How does the full code matter anyway? It will just be a call to the database to check if the user/password combo is accurate.

Comment: There are a thousand ways to make networking calls so the ability to do a timeout is dependent on how you are doing it.

Comment: mention the library you are using like alamofire or afnetworking, etc with your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `Alamofire` below is the code to define timeout

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10 // seconds
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

also you don't need to manage it through timer, as timer will fire exactly after 10 seconds, irrelevant whether your API get response or not, just manage it with timeout.

and here is how you manage timeout

```
self.alamofireManager!.request(.POST, "myURL", parameters:params)
.responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            //do json stuff
        case .Failure(let error):
            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
               //call your function here for timeout
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajat. How do I call a function when it does timeout? Suppose I want to call some `myFunc()` when AlamoFire times out.

Comment: Edited my answer to handle timeout, please check.

Comment: When I use just `Alamofire`, my request is working fine. When I use `Alamorefire.Manager`, it says `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey`

Comment: The `init()` solution doesn't work for me, because I don't have any `init()` calls in my code. Is there anyway to pass configuration to `Alamofire` itself? Instead of a manager?

Comment: try it in viedDidLoad

Answer (score 20):

Here is the solution for Swift 4

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
   // Excecute after 3 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func loginFunc() {

    delay(10.0){
        //time is up, show network error
        //return should break out of the function (not tested)
        return
    }

    //authentication code
```